# Make multiple instances of a lambda function write to the same document

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am not entirely sure if this is even possible so I was hoping someone could steer me in the correct direction. I have an AWS project that is triggered when files are placed in my AWS bucket. The project processes the file and creates an output document.

While the project is processing the file, I send certain email notifications such as "File ____ has been processed successfully" or "File ____ has failed". Instead of getting all of these individual emails, is it possible to just write all of this to some document and after all files are done processing, email the document to myself?

I am not sure that this is possible though because how will each instance of the lambda function have access to the same file?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "document"? Are there multiple instances of a lambda, processing one file each? And you want a single email at the end with the results (in terms of "file _ succeeded/failed" etc)?

Comment: By document I mean just an Excel document, but I can turn a .txt file into an excel doc, so I'm not worried about that part. But yes, there are multiple instances because each instance is processing one file. They are all ran at 5pm everyday. So I want to write statements to the same file from all instances

Comment: To me the main issue is: how do you know when all the files have been processed? Concurrent writes is not a problem as you can design your process to handle that (for example, each lambda writes to its own file in a certain folder, they can later be combined). But how do you know when all files have been processed, unless you know ahead of time how many to expect?

Comment: Good point. As of right now I have no way to determine that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to introduce an SQS FIFO queue. Trigger one set of Lambdas from file uploads to S3, have those Lambdas write necessary details to SQS, and have SQS trigger a second set of Lambdas that actually write to the XLSX file. That way you won't have multiple concurrent XLSX writers.